# Will Azure Search Filter Queries Perform Type Coercion?

Tags: odata, azure-cognitive-search

Specifically for a boolean value, will Azure Search filter query perform type coercion? Every single filterable value that a user might select for their search in my application is a string value. When building my OData query, I don't want to have to perform logic to check on this one boolean value to adjust the query string accordingly when a dozen other values are just strings. I just want to be able to wrap every single value in a single quote, the logic is more simple this way, as opposed to wrapping values in single quotes for everything except boolean values, etc.

I don't have the means to test this while our index is being built but I am writing our client side code for this in preparation for when it does exist.

So, for example, let's say I have a boolean flag called "isDeleted" which indicates if a record in my database has been "sudo" deleted or not, that is added to my search index. If I add the following filter to my payload post to Azure Search, will I get records back that this value is true:

`...
"filter": "isDeleted eq 'true'"
...`

Notice I am wrapping the "true" value in single quotes, indicating it could be a string. Will the Azure Search engine perform type coercion on this and pull back records, or is a valid filter only

`...
"filter": "isDeleted eq true"
...`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Search only supports type conversions defined in the OData standard. Specifically, widening numeric conversions are supported, which is why you can compare a double with an integer, for example. Azure Search does not allow any automatic conversions to or from strings in filter expressions.